# Find elements in stream where the property to check is async

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dart, dart-async

Using [webdriver](https://github.com/google/webdriver.dart) I select the elements of the first column of a grid and want to check if the element with the text `Task 499` is part of the result.
CSS doesn't allow selectors referring text content which would allow to just get the one element in question in the first place.

```
const firstColumnSelector = const By.cssSelector(
    'app-element::shadow #myGrid::shadow div.bwu-datagrid-cell.l0');

bool lastRowVisible = driver.findElements(firstColumnSelector)
    .contains((e) => e.text == 'Task 499' && e.displayed);
```

This doesn't work because `e.text` returns `Future<String>` instead of `String` and `e.displayed` returns `Future<bool>` instead of `bool` and
`contains()` also only accepts `bool` but not `Future<bool>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using `asyncMap()`

```
const firstColumnSelector = const By.cssSelector(
    'app-element::shadow #myGrid::shadow div.bwu-datagrid-cell.l0');

bool lastRowVisible = driver.findElements(firstColumnSelector)
    .asyncMap((e) async => await e.text == 'Task 499' && await e.displayed)
    .contains(true);
```